# How to apply nth-child either odd or even in reversed order?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a list of alternating colored divs (red or green). 
I am inserting new divs at the top of the list and I want the existing divs to keep their color.

Is there any way to apply nth:child(odd) to the list of divs but in reverse? The way it works now is that the top div will always be green and the bottom div will change color using nth:child odd or even.

Comment: Please share your works.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`:nth-last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child).

It uses the same logic as `:nth-child`, but reversed.

Working example (I can't use SASS here, so please see the equivalent CSS):

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('#parent');
const button = document.querySelector('#button');

let count = 0;

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
  const child = document.createElement('div');
  child.classList.add('child');
  child.textContent = ++count;
  parent.insertBefore(child, parent.firstChild);
});
```

```css
#parent {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: white;
}

.child:nth-last-child(odd) {
  background-color: green;
}

.child:nth-last-child(even) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Add Child</button>

<div id="parent">
  <div class="child">0</div>
</div>
```